# Would you consider this JSON.parse behaviour to be a vulnerability

Tags: javascript, json

If you evaluate the below Javascript snippet it will pop an alert box.

```js
JSON.parse('{"sometext'-alert(document.domain,document.URL)-'":"somevalue"}');
```

the fix would to make sure that the string if coming from an untrusted source is to be sanitized/escaped.
However I would have the JSON.parse method just error out saying that this is not a valid JSON string.
Why is that code being executed.

Comment: how is that vulnerable? to what? who'd write that code? - it's not like you could get that from a request = the code is executed because that's how you wrote the CODE ... JSON doesn't "get executed" when it is parsed ... the argument you've created runs something before JSON.parse gets a string to parse

Comment: I am trying to give the worst examples but say the JSON was created based on string concatenation based on user input. Something akin to SQLi. What I am trying to get at is why is JSON.parse evaluating JS instead of just erroring out..

Comment: JSON.parse does not evaluate JS ... JS evaluates JS, into a string, and passes it to `JSON.parse` - again, how are you going to get any vulnerability ... unless you use something like `eval` of a user input - but then, it's not JSON.parse that is vulnerable ... it's eval ... and YOUR code

Comment: Understood, T.J. Crowder's, example drove it home. like I said missed the obvious :) by focusing on ```JSON.parse```. Thanks!

Comment: And this is why I love SO, got the answer in <5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cause that behavior if your starting point is a **string**. Your starting point is JavaScript code, and what you have just uses JavaScript code in the process of creating a string, exactly like this with no JSON in sight:

```js
const str = '"sometext'-alert(document.domain,document.URL)-'"';
```

So no, there's no **JSON**-based vulnerability here. If you're running code you get from elsewhere, that's the vulnerability.

Comment: This makes sense, I was so focused on the JSON.parse call that I missed the obvious. Thanks!